# Cómo imprimir un PDF que está dentro de un div automáticamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, vue.js, imprimir

Les explico que actualmente trabajo en una aplicación web que genera un archivo PDF al realizar una venta, este archivo PDF se muestra en un modal para ser impreso por es usuario, así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo funciona perfectamente, pero ahora el usuario quiere que al momento de terminar la venta se abra la ventana de impresión del navegador automáticamente, es decir, así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente con el tamaño de papel predeterminado de la ticketera y todo eso.
Quisiera saber si eso es posible, ya lo intenté con la librería **jquery.printarea** pero solo me imprime una hoja en blanco. Ahora les comento que el archivo PDF esta en un elemento HTML **iframe** entonces ya traté con:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" :src="ruta_comprobante"></iframe>
```

y

```
$("#imprimir").printArea()
```

lo que abre la ventana de impresión del navegador pero con una hoja en blanco.
También me di cuenta que el elemento **iframe** abre un nuevo documento HTML y este documento HTML a su vez tiene un elemento **embed** en donde muestra el archivo PDF con todas las opciones incluyendo el botón de impresión, entonces habrá una forma de hacer que cuando cargue el archivo HTML dentro del elemento **iframe** se disparé el evento del botón imprimir del archivo PDF?

Esa es mi pregunta.

Ahora lo que tengo es el siguiente código en mi **HTML**:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="imprimir">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" :src="ruta_comprobante"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Entonces, con eso muestro un archivo PDF dentro del elemento **iframe**, este elemento creo que trae toda una página web y lo muestra dentro de sí, esa página web contiene un archivo PDF como se muestra más arriba, la idea es imprimir ese archivo PDF, así como la segunda imagen.

La alternativa de abrir el archivo PDF en otra pestaña y usar `window.print()` no es viable ya que los documentos pueden ser de tamaño A4 o de ticket (55mm).

Espero que alguien tenga una respuesta a mi duda a si sea que no se puede por ciertas razones para no seguir perdiendo mi tiempo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Quieres algo como esto ??

** *REDACTADO* **

Siguiendo lo solicitado de solo imprimir el contenido de un div
Puedes realizar algo como esto:

En este caso, hay 2 imágenes, una dentro de un div, otra fuera de este,
Gracias a la función, solo la que está dentro del div, será impresa.

```js
function printDiv(nombreDiv) {
     var contenido = document.getElementById(nombreDiv).innerHTML;
     var contenidoOriginal= document.body.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = contenido;
     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;
}
```

```html
<div id="areaImprimir">
  <h3>
    <center>Mi contenido</center>
  </h3>
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog" />
</div>
<img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/cat" />
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('areaImprimir')" value="imprimir div" />
```

Comment: Gracias Excorpion, ya intenté eso mismo, pero eso imprime toda la página y yo solo quiero imprimir el pdf.

Comment: Por favor checkea de nuevo la respuesta y dime si es tu respuesta.

Comment: Codigo y esas cosas ponlos en la publicacion. La idea es que crees un [mre] para poder replicarlo

Comment: Hola Excorpion, acabo de editar la publicación incluyendo el código de lo que quiero imprimir, creo que no es lo mismo imprimir un div que contiene imágenes y otros elementos HTML a imprimir un iframe que no contiene elementos HTML pero que muestra un contenido a partir de una ruta.